# Angular2 service doesn't retrieve nested array from the json

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I spent a lot of the time to resolve this issue.

I have webapi returning json like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "testName",
  "address": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "address_name": 'testname'
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "address_name": 'testname'
    }
  ]
}
```

In the angular2 I have service like this:

```
public getRoutes():Observable<Route[]>
{
      return this.http.get(this.BASE_API_URL+'/Routes')
             .map(res=>res.json());
}
```

and in the component I have piece of code to retrieve data to array variable

```
this.routeService.getRoutes().subscribe(
       (routes) => {
           for(let route of routes){
                mainInstance.routes.push(route);
           }
           console.log("Routes filled");
       }
);
```

json result contains filled simple attributes like id or name, but inner array address is empty. Do you know guys what I am working bad?
Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like to me that you are returning an object with a nested array, but you are trying to treat the parent object itself as an array.

If you service returns

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "testName",
  "address": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "address_name": 'testname'
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "address_name": 'testname'
    }
  ]
}
```

Then update the signature of your service function:

```
public getRoutes():Observable<Route>
{
      return this.http.get(this.BASE_API_URL+'/Routes')
             .map(res=>res.json());
}
```

Where `Route` is an interface that looks like this:

```
export interface Route{
   id:number;
   name:string;
   address: Address[];
}
export interface Address{
   id: number;
   address_name: string;
}
```

And if you want to use the `address` array in your component, then access that property like this:

```
this.routeService.getRoutes().subscribe(
       routes => {
           for(let route of routes.address){
                mainInstance.routes.push(route);
           }
           console.log("Routes filled");
       }
);
```

This way you are accessing the `address` field specifically that is the array, not the parent object.

Comment: routes.address is Array(0). So I am not able to read that property. But when I open webapi page, I see correct results.  It's really strange behaviour. I was trying to add some settings into map of the service byt without any success.

Comment: I just edited the answer to show how to structure your model.  It looks like your signature on the service function doesn't match what is actually being returned, which throws off the TypeScript compiler.